# How can I programmatically replace the contents of the current db with a .sqlite3 file in a rails app running on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, heroku

When a certain request hits my app I would like to reset the database back to its original state which is backed up in an sqlite3 file. I'd appreciate any help.

The app is hosted on heroku.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the database back to its original state?" Does this mean you want to erase all of the data?

Comment: I want to erase all of the data in the current db and replace it with the data in an .sqlite3 file. You can do this on heroku with 'heroku db:push' but I need a way to do it programmatically. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks promising: http://addons.heroku.com/bundles